# WKWebView and redirect 302 responses

Tags: ios, ios9, wkwebview, ios10, http-status-code-302

I believe `WKWebView` will open pages if the response has a status of 302.  Can I stop the redirection from happening?  Is there a delegate method that I can implement to decide if it should continue to navigate to the new resource?

```
optional func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void)
```

Does not seem to be called if there was a redirection.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Hope you find some workaround. If any, please share. Its urgent

Comment: agreed. That delegate is not invoked on redirect. At least as of iOS 10. There appears - as yet - no way to prevent the redirect.

Comment: Noway in `WKWebView`. However I use URLSession to send the request instead and capture 302 by myself do this trick. Maybe you should have a try